# offline access to google calendar across the organization

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-calendar-api

Assuming there is admin of all the company's mails (hosted by google) - is there any way the admin can give [3rd party app to integrate with google calendars](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/) of part of company's employees? 
I think of a way to "save" the integration per employee and have "single" integration configuration by one person.

Comment: Can you give us some more information please?   One define 'hosted by google' Is this a google domains account?   what third party integration?

Comment: I don't think OAuth2 allows a third-party (even the admin) to request a token on your behalf.